# Flask flash not working after redirect

Tags: python, flask, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I'm having an issue in which the flash messages aren't showing the messages set before a redirect. I created a simple project to reproduce the problem. The redirect flash message doesn't show with or without the SERVER_NAME config file but the regular flash message always shows.

```
import sys
import os.path

from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, url_for


class TestConfig:
    DEBUG = True
    SERVER_NAME = 'project-username.c9users.io'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'my_secret_key'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('This is a regular test flash')
    return render_template('test.html')


@app.route('/flash')
def flash_it():
    flash('This is a redirect test flash')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

And the template:

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
{{ message }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**

I attempted to call this from the command line using localhost instead of the domain name that I have through the cloud9 interface. And it worked fine.

```
$ wget -q -O - "$@" http://localhost:8080/flash

This is a redirect test flash

This is a regular test flash
```

I have the SERVER_NAME variable set to the correct name but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and template exactly and got both flashes showing up when I go to `localhost:8080/flash`. What version of Python are you using and are you accessing `/flash`?

Comment: This is with Python 3.4.3. Because of your comment I created another virtualenv with 2.7.6 and have the same problem. This is with Flask 0.10.1. And yes, I'm accessing /flash.

Comment: Turns out it's server name related. Updated original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turns out to be related to the SERVER_NAME. It should not contain the subdomain name.

Changing the config to the following makes it work with the Cloud9 domain name:

```
class TestConfig:
    DEBUG = True
    SERVER_NAME = 'project-username.c9users.io'
```

Comment: This is not exactly the solution that worked for me, but made me think of the problem: For me the problem was that I had this line:
`app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/some-route`
Which was messing up the flash mechanism when testing in localhost.